# tkinter and subprocess are blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

If I click on the button then it's blocked. if I remove subprocess then it's ok.

How can I fix it ?

I guess that I need to use thread but I don't know how...

```
btn_add_calc = Button(window, text="Add calculation", command=calc_data)
btn_add_calc.pack(pady=10)


def calc_data():
    btn_add_calc.config(text="Calculating...")
  
    res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    text.insert(INSERT, f"{res[0]}\n")
```

Comment: What are you going to use `res` for? Can you please provide a minimal working example. If you aren't going to use `res` in your GUI, you can just run the `subprocess.check_output(...)` in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to declare a variable, just run:
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

Comment: OP is using `res` later in their code. The problem will still persist because tkinter can't update itself while the `subprocess.check_output(...)` is running.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the problems with my previous answer I came up with this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading


text_to_add_to_output = []

def display_output_loop():
    while len(text_to_add_to_output) != 0:
        text.insert("end", text_to_add_to_output.pop(0))
    text.after(100, display_output_loop)


def calc_data():
    btn_add_calc.config(text="Calculating...")
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target=calculation, daemon=True)
    new_thread.start()

def calculation():
    global result
    # I changed this part so that I can test the script:
    cmd = "ping 8.8.8.8 -n 5"
    res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode()
    result = res.replace("\r\n", "\n").lstrip("\n")+"\n\n\n\n"
    text_to_add_to_output.append(result)


root = tk.Tk()

btn_add_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Start Calculation", command=calc_data)
btn_add_calc.pack()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

display_output_loop()

root.mainloop()
```

It creates a new thread that calls the `subprocess.check_output()`. Because it's in a new thread, it doesn't effect `tkinter`'s `mainloop` so the window doesn't become unresponsive.

It uses a queue named: `text_to_add_to_output`, that holds all of the data that should be added to the `text` widget. It's thread safe, so it shouldn't raise any errors.

Comment: Why can't I call insert and subProcess from the same function (calculation) ? @TheLizzard

Comment: @Alex Parts of `tkinter` aren't thread safe. That means that if you call `text.insert()` from another thread (where I call the `subprocess.check_output()`), it might raise an error inside `tkinter`. Most of the time it's fine but in some cases `tkinter` can just panic.

Comment: Can I use more than one subprocess in function ? It seems stuck if I use 5 subprocesses @TheLizzard

Comment: @Alex You should be able to use as many `subprocess`es as you want as long as you put them in the `calculation` function.